# Attach method for events

Tags: sapui5

I have a question about attach functions on controls.

For example, `sap.m.Input` has several `attach*` methods, one of them is `attachLiveChange`. The question is, does it exist a common `attach` method?

What am I trying to archive is, for example:

```
oInput.attach("LiveChange", (oEvent) => doSomething);
```

Answer (score 0):

sap.ui.base.EventProvider has a method called attachEvent and attachEventOnce, most controls derive from the EventProvider class so you can use said methods to achieve your goal.

https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.EventProvider/methods/attachEvent
https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.ui.base.EventProvider/methods/attachEventOnce